# Docker API logs JWT issue

Tags: api, docker

I am using Docker to run containers for an app that uses Angular, Identity Server, and an API(using a Compose.yml file to run them all together).

The API is responsible for returning database info, based on the user logged in through Identity Server. Locally, the API returns the user info after login without any issues. However, when I use Docker to run the app, the user can login but not have their db info returned to the angular page. I checked the logs for the API container, and am receiving the following errors:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[3]
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
```

So it appears to me that there is an issue with the API receiving the token. I only see these error messages **after** I login through ID server. The ID server container logs do not display any errors before or after I login.

Can someone help me resolve this issue?